# WCF REST - problem in hosting on IIS 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, iis-6

I am hosting my WCF REST on IIS6 and calling it from my WPF application.

Following is the endpoint:

I get following error :

Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Comment: Got the answer. I need to add .* in configuration

Comment: If you've found the solution to the problem, the appropriate course of action is to post that solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer. I need to add `.*` in configuration in IIS.

Comment: now we just need you to mark this as the answer for everyone else to know.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases this exception indicates that  something on your machine is blocking your connection. Try running it with firewall/anti virus disabled.